# If $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ and $\lim_{n \to\infty} b_n=\infty$. Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n b_n= \pm\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $$\forall M<0: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}:\forall n > N: a_nb_n < M$$ for $a<0$ and $$\forall M>0: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}:\forall n > N: a_nb_n >M$$ for $a>0$

I have tried to use the definitions of convergent and divergent sequences on $a_n$ and $b_n$ and tried to link them to the above mentioned defitions but i have failed to do so.

I have also attempted a proof by contradiction by showing that $a_nb_n$ converge to some arbitrary value $L$ and to show that this doesnt work by saying $b_n$ diverges to infinity, but I dont think my reasoning is correct.

Please someone guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Hint: use the formal definition of the limit of a sequence.

Comment: Hint: you have not yet used the limit of $a_n$'s